# YouTube Embedded Video JavaScript API Failed to execute postMessage on DOMWindow The target origin provided doesn't match

Tags: javascript, video, youtube-api

When I run an embedded YouTube video with an `iframe` in my Chrome browser using the YouTube Embedded Video JavaScript API, I'm getting the following error in my console:

`www-widgetapi.js:581 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://symfony.XXXXXX.com')`.

I'm serving the web-page containing the `iframe` who's `src` attribute is set to the YouTube video's URL along with several settings in URL search parameters, including the *`origin`* parameter set to my web-page's URL. Here is the `iframe`:

```
"<iframe width="480" height="390" frameborder="0"
         src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rs50Ie1dHXg?autohide=1&autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=0&controls=0&disablekb=1&enablejsapi=1&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&start=0&widgetid=1&origin=https://symfony.XXXXXX.com"
         allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>"
```

I've verified the above against the YouTube object contents after executing the following statements, and the YouTube API object properly had the above values.  Here are the statements that I'm using to create the YouTube API object:

```
const IFRAME = document.querySelector( 'iframe#YouTube-Player.YouTube-iframe' );
const $IFRAME = $( IFRAME );

var switches = { 'autohide' :       1,   'autoplay' :       1,
                 'cc_load_policy' : 0,   'controls' :       0,
                 'disablekb' :      1,   'enablejsapi' :    1,
                 'fs' :             0,   'iv_load_policy' : 3,
                 'modestbranding' : 1,   'rel' :            0,
                 'showinfo' :       0,   'start' :          0,
                 'widgetid' :       1,
                 'origin' :         window.location.origin };

//
// In my code I have a function that reads the switches object and assigns its
// contents them as a string to the iframe's src attribute, but for simplicity,
// I'm assigning that content directly to the end of the YouTube Video URL that
// I'm setting the iframe's src attribute to.
//

var str_switches = '?autohide=1&autoplay=1' +
                   '&cc_load_policy=0&controls=0' +
                   '&disablekb=1&enablejsapi=1' +
                   '&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3' +
                   '&modestbranding=1&rel=0' +
                   '&showinfo=0&start=0' +
                   '&widgetid=1' +
                   '&origin=https://symfony.######.com";

IFRAME.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/rs50Ie1dHXg' +
             '?autohide=1&autoplay=1' +
             '&cc_load_policy=0&controls=0' +
             '&disablekb=1&enablejsapi=1' +
             '&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3' +
             '&modestbranding=1&rel=0' +
             '&showinfo=0&start=0' +
             '&widgetid=1' +
             '&origin=https://symfony.######.com";

var youtubePlayer = new YT.Player( 'YouTube-Player',
                                   { videoId :    'rs50Ie1dHXg',
                                     width :      Math.max( IFRAME.clientWidth,
                                                            $IFRAME.width() ),
                                     height :     Math.max( IFRAME.clientHeight,
                                                            $IFRAME.height() ),
                                     name :       'a_blank',
                                     playerVars : switches,
                                     events :     { 'onError' :      onError,
                                                    'onReady' :       onPlayerReady,
                                                    'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange }
                                                  } );
```

I'm not showing the `onError`, `onPlayerReady`, and `onStateChange` event handlers, but they work, the video plays, and the `onPlayerReady`, and `onStateChange` event handler functions are properly called, allowing me to monitor the progress of the video as it plays, pauses, and finishes.

As others have already said, this message is misleading.  Yes, unless I was running my site from the YouTube site, there would be no other valid reason that my site's `origin` would match the target `origin`.  So obviously, the YouTube API is complaining about something else.

I looked at all of the Stack Overflow issues on this subject, as well as what I could find on the Internet, but either there weren't any answers, what answers were given didn't apply, or trying the few that seemed helpful, didn't resolve the error that I'm getting, including that I needed to be running my web-site with an HTTPS URL and just leaving out the `origin` parameter.

Why is the *Failed to execute postMessage...* error occurring and what impact does it have on my ability to monitor and control the video's play.

Thank you.

Comment: Same problem. Surprised no one has answered this yet. Every answer I find says make sure both origin and target are HTTPS. But, that's isn't the case with your problem or mine. Did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Similar issue, same diagnostic, it started some time ago on a wordpress site (with avia editor) where formerly the videos loaded without issue. As far as I can tell no updates or changes to the site have intervened so I was chalking it up to some youtube policy/API changes.Both sites are https and dicking around with http/https target/source changes nothing. Unfortunately the message appears to cover a wide array of unrelated issues.

Comment: It seems, that this request here that your are making, seems to have an issue on your side. 

As, it works fine for me.
I would try it on a different host to see if that fixes anything.

Comment: I ever made an app that controlling the Youtube iframe, it was not easy. but it could be resolved by making it to be PWA

Comment: Pretty sure it has nothing to do with Youtube but problem with your site.

I just copied the above iframe into codesandbox and it loads without the above error.
Ref: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-moon-y5146?file=/src/index.js